# Ajax Pagination Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

I'm trying to make a pagination with ajax and laravel 5, but I can not do the ajax works even with simple tests:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
$('.pager a').on('click', function (e) {
var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
         e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: 'testeserver.php',
         //url:"raphael.dev/testeserver.php",
         dataType: 'json', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
         success:function(json){

             alert("Success"+json);
         },
         error:function(){
             alert("Error");
         }      
      });
    });
});
```

In this example I try one have a return on json ,

```
  <?php
$arr = array("element1","element2",array("element31","element32"));
$arr['name'] = "response";
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($arr).");";
?>
```

but only with the error alert , in fact I'm trying with these following cases :

BlogController:

```
  public function index(Request $request){
          $artigos = Artigo::where('publicado_em', '<=', Carbon::now())
            ->orderBy('publicado_em', 'desc')
            ->paginate(config('blog.artigos_por_pagina'));


        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return Response::json(view('Blog.artigos', compact('artigos'))->render());
        }
        return view('Blog.index', compact('artigos'));
    }
```

routes.php

```
post('/', 'BlogController@index');
get('/', 'BlogController@index');
get('/{slug}', 'BlogController@show');
```

jquery

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
$('.pager a').on('click', function (e) {
var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
         e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'page=' + page,
         dataType: 'json',
         success:function(json){

             alert("Success"+json);
         },
         error:function(){
             alert("Error");
         }      
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: which part is not working??

Comment: Remove the `dd($artigos);` part. You wont receive a valid json string so javascript can't work with it.

Comment: @mimo the dd($artigos) was just a test, and i forget to took it off, so yeah without it still not working.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju the first part was just a test with the testeserver.php and a ajax get, but dosent work, and what i'm trying to do is in the second part , make a pagination with ajax but still my two trys with ajax dosent work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution, changed my jquery code to :

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
$('.pager a').on('click', function (e) {
          var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
          e.preventDefault();
          var url = '?page=' + page; 
$.post( url, function(data) {
        alert( "success"+data );
      })
        .done(function() {
          alert( "second success" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
          alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function() {
          alert( "finished" );
      });
```

And found a error in my BlogController :

in

```
 if ($request->ajax()) {
 return Response::json(view('Blog.artigos', compact('artigos'))->render());
    }
```

the Facade Response was not declared, so just added

```
Use Request;
```

at the top,

but i still dont understand why the $ajax() dosent work, just the $get and $post

Answer (score 0):

Laravel protects your application with `CSRF` tokens. When utilising Ajax you need to be sure to send across the `CSRF` token, otherwise Laravel will not process the request to protect your app.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test',
    type: "post",
    data: {'_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
    success: function (data) {
        alert('the joys'); 
    },
    complete: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Notice the `$('input[name=_token]').val()` - that will send your `CSRF` token. You will of course need to create a hidden input with the `CSRF` token in your view.

[More information can be found here!](http://engageinteractive.co.uk/blog/csrf-protection-with-ajax-and-laravel)

Comment: Yeah i tried this, but i dont have a form submit, so thats not the problem, i solved this already, will post the solution now, just a error in the BlogController.